# Neovide: How to paste with SHIFT+INSERT?

Tags: paste, neovide

I normally use vim and neovim on the Gnome Terminal where I can paste from the Gnome clipboard with SHIFT+INSERT but this does not work in neovide (Arch Linux AUR package neovide-git 0.7.0.r336.g86aa275-1).

How can I enable clipboard paste with SHIFT+INSERT in neovide like it works in normal vim/nvim from the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Make a new configuration file for GUI configuration as:

```bash
~/.config/nvim/ginit.vim
```

After that, add the below line to paste using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd> as:

```bash
map! <S-Insert> <C-R>+
```